# Calling dask inside dask spawned process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

We have a large project that comprises of numerous tasks. We use a dask graph to schedule each task. A small sample of the graph is as follows. Note that dask is set to multiprocessing mode.

dask_graph:

```
  universe: !!python/tuple [gcsstrategies.svc.business_service.UniverseService.load_universe_object, CONTEXT]
  raw_market_data: !!python/tuple [gcsstrategies.svc.data_loading_service.RDWLoader.load_market_data, CONTEXT, universe]
  raw_fundamental_data: !!python/tuple [gcsstrategies.svc.data_loading_service.RDWLoader.load_fundamental_data, CONTEXT, universe]

dask_keys: [raw_fundamental_data]
```

Now one of the tasks, `raw_fundamental_data`, lazily schedules dask tasks using `@delay` and runs them using `dask.compute()`. The reason for this design choice is the list of tasks that will be scheduled and lazily run by dask within `raw_fundamental_data` are dynamically chosen at runtime based on runtime parameters.

The error we see is:

> daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

We understand this is because a spawned process is trying to spawn children. Is there any solution to this problem? Does dask have any way to allow a task scheduled via daskgraph to schedule and lazily run its own tasks either using `@delay` or another method.

Please note that in our system there are numerous tasks that will run their own tasks using multiprocessing. So sequential execution is not an option.

Answer (score 5):

The multiprocessing scheduler is not capable of this kind of operation.  However, the [distributed scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is (also you can easily use the distributed scheduler on a single machine.

Relevant doc pages are here:

- http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/task-launch.html
- http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html

#### Here is a small example

```
In [1]: from dask.distributed import Client, local_client

In [2]: def f(n):
   ...:     with local_client() as lc:
   ...:         futures = [lc.submit(lambda x: x + 1, i) for i in range(n)]
   ...:         total = lc.submit(sum, futures)
   ...:         return total.result()
   ...:     

In [3]: c = Client()  # start processes on local machine

In [4]: future = c.submit(f, 10)

In [5]: future.result()
Out[5]: 55
```

This uses the concurrent.futures interface to dask rather than [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html), but you can use dask.delayed just as well.  See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manage-computation.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So clean and simple. Your solution worked perfectly. Although I was not able to get the @delayed working so I opted for using your method of using the local_client().

Comment: @MRocklin Is it a valid use-case if I connect to the same Dask Distributed cluster from inside the delayed/submitted function? (i.e. `lc = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')`) I seem to get a deadlock when I try to do so and use "published" datasets; should I report it?

Comment: See [distributed.worker_client](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/task-launch.html#submit-tasks-from-worker)

Comment: @MRocklin Perfect! Every time I stuck somewhere in Dask, I just need to re-read the documentation as Dask evolves blazingly fast heading ahead of my thoughts :)